# can we optimize google app engine index, if one index set is subset of other

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using two indexes for query in my code. these indexes are :

Index1 :

```
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="false" source="auto">
    <property name="type" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="star_value" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="close_date" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Index2 :

```
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="false" source="auto">
    <property name="type" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="star_value" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="close_date" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="lead_value" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Q. Google app engine is saying that we can optimize index to reduce it.Can we work with only index2 as it has all property of index1 and it is in proper order and location top to down ?

Comment: depends on how your query look like. I don't think your query will use both indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You will need both indexes if you run queries based on them.

Depending on your use case, you may use only index 1 to retrieve all matching entities, and then loop through the results and keep only those that match "lead_value" filter.

This approach is a good idea if the following two conditions are met: (1) you find a relatively small number of entities after applying the first 3 filters, and (2) you have a very large number of entities to start with or you update these entities very frequently, so removing an extra index results in significant savings in writing/data storage costs.